# Template template collection accepting another template argument

Tags: c++, templates, generic-programming

I'm trying to wrap my head around how template templates work to implement a similar functionality as shown below.

Consider two classes (in Java). The first class is limiting the collection returned by `pack` method by specifying that only an object of the second template argument can be stored in it:

```
abstract class ContainerPacker<T, Container extends Collection<T>> {
    abstract Container pack(T t);
}
```

And implementation of this class for, let's say, `Integer` type could then look like this:

```
class IntegerContainerPacker extends ContainerPacker<Integer, List<Integer>> {
    @Override
    List<Integer> pack(Integer t) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(t);
        list.add(t);
        return list;
    }
}
```

Now I'd like to do something similar in C++ using template templates. Notice how the `Container` is a template itself:

```
template <typename T, template <typename U> class Container>
class ContainerPacker {
  public:
    virtual Container<T> pack(T) = 0;
};
```

I'm having trouble implementing it though. The code below does not compile:

```
class IntegerVectorPacker : public ContainerPacker<int, std::vector> {
  public:
    std::vector<int> pack(int t) {
        std::vector<int> v = std::vector<int>();
        v.push_back(t);
        return v;
    }
};
```

The errors are:

> error: type/value mismatch at argument 2 in template parameter list for ‘template class Container> class ContainerPacker’
>    class IntegerVectorPacker : public ContainerPacker {

and

> note:   expected a template of type ‘template class Container’, got ‘template class std::vector’

I've been looking for an answer but it's even difficult to figure out what question to ask. Template templates are hard.

Comment: The second error you mention seems to be related to the fact that you supply `std::vector` as the second template parameter, instead of providing the full-specialization which is `std::vector<int>`. It is saying that it expected a template class but you provided a class name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
template <typename T, template <typename...> class Container>
```

The problem (a problem?) in your code is that `std::vector` is a template class that receive more than one templates argument (two: the second one has a default type); so doesn't match `Container`.

Defining `Container` as receiving zero or more templates should permit the match with `std::vector<int>` (that really is `std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>`) and other containers.

**-- EDIT --**

I see now that you have tagger this question C++ and not C++11 (or newer).

The `typename...` suggestion is valid only starting from C++11 because variadic templates aren't available before.

For C++98 you can write

```
template <typename T, template <typename, typename> class Container>
```

but this works only with two parameters containers.

**-- EDIT 2 --**

Off Topic suggestion.

If you can use C++11 or newer (so variadic templates) switch the order of `Container` and `T` for `ContainerPacker` and transform `T` is a variadic pack; something like

```
template <template <typename...> class Container, typename ... Ts>
class ContainerPacker {
  public:
    virtual Container<Ts...> pack(Ts...) = 0;
};
```

It's much more flexible.

Comment: Oh, that's perfect! I noticed that it has multiple template arguments but the second one is defaulted, so I thought it can be omitted. Anyways, it works, thank you (:

Comment: @Jezor - Added an off topic suggestion (in case you can use C++11 or newer)

Comment: Thank you again (: I'm using C++11 and actually, I've been wondering about how to specify other template arguments in the implementation

Comment: By the way, do you have any resources where you got your answer from or did you just play around with the code to see what works / made the answer from your experience? I'd love to read more about templates in C++, specifically C++11